# CSV Import validation

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to set up an import/export to MySQL for a CSV file. I have most of it, however I am trying to validate the information. When I validate I want none of the records to be imported to MySQL. The code I currently have will only not import any records after an empty field. I wouldn't normally ask but I am stumped.

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';
$empty_value_found = false;
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen ($file,"r");

while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false){
    $first = trim($fileop[0]);
    $last = trim($fileop[1]);
    $birthday = trim($fileop[2]);
    $age = trim($fileop[3]);
    $address = trim($fileop[4]);


    if (
        empty($first) 
        || empty($last) 
        || empty($birthday) 
        || empty($age) 
        || empty($address) 
    ) {
        $empty_value_found = true;
        echo "empty field please check";
        break; // stop our while-loop
    }
}
// now we check - if there no empty values
if (!$empty_value_found) {
// we can go through our file again and insert values,
// code is similar to what you have

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `mytable` (first, last, birthday, age, address) VALUES ('$first','$last','$birthday','$age','$address')");
    $getdata =  "SELECT * FROM mytable";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn,$getdata);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >=1){
        echo "<table><tr><th>First</th><th>Last</th><th>Birthday</th><th>Age</th> <th>Address</th></tr>";
    }
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["first"]. "</td><td>" . $row["last"]. "</td><td>" . $row["birthday"]. "</td><td>" . $row["age"]. "</td><td>" . $row["address"].  "</td></tr>";
    }
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: And where is the validation code?

Comment: I have used if(empty($_FILES["file"]['tmp_name']))
    {echo "field missing";
die(); and if(!isset($firstname) || trim($firstname) == '')
{
   echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
}

Comment: So what's the problem? What do you try to validate - that someone uploaded a file or that file has non-empty rows in it?

Comment: empty fields. if there is any empty field the file should not be imported and the script should stop.

Comment: Empty fields of what? of `$_FILES` array?

Comment: This script should check for any empty fields contained within my CSV file. I have five fields first, last, birthday, age, address in a csv file. If any field is left blank in the csv file when it is imported the script should not import any of the records, however if any records proceed the record with a blank field they are inserted into my database when they should not be.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's see:

```
// here you get an array from csv-string
while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false){
    // first: use trim function to remove spaces from left and right of a value
    $first = trim($fileop[0]);
    $last = trim($fileop[1]);
    $birthday = trim($fileop[2]);
    $age = trim($fileop[3]);
    $address = trim($fileop[4]);

    // now you have five values.
    // u want to insert them to database only if they are ALL not empty
    // use function empty to check if value is empty
    if (!empty($first) 
        && !empty($last) 
        && !empty($birthday) 
        && !empty($age) 
        && !empty($address) 
    ) {
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `mytable` (first, last, birthday, age, address) VALUES ('$first','$last','$birthday','$age','$address')");

        // other code here
    }
}
```

This script will insert values which are not empty. But still it will ignore rows with empty values.
If you want to check if all fields in all rows of your csv are not empty, then you should do this:

```
// set a special flag
$empty_value_found = false;

while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false){
    // first: use trim function to remove spaces from left and right of a value
    $first = trim($fileop[0]);
    $last = trim($fileop[1]);
    $birthday = trim($fileop[2]);
    $age = trim($fileop[3]);
    $address = trim($fileop[4]);

    // now you have five values.
    // if any of them is empty - we should NOT go further and stop our cycle
    if (empty($first) 
        || empty($last) 
        || empty($birthday) 
        || empty($age) 
        || empty($address) 
    ) {
        $empty_value_found = true;
        break; // stop our while-loop
    }
}
// now we check - if there no empty values
if (!$empty_value_found) {
    // we can go through our file again and insert values,
    // code is similar to what you have
}
```

So if you want to check

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However maybe it is the way I am structuring the code but I keep getting "fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource" I have updated the php in the original question

Comment: where is your $handle value? you should do something like this: `$handle = fopen($uploadcsv, 'r');` that error is because your $handle is probabily empty/null

Comment: So this does block ANY entries from being entered I got that part and it is working. However with a valid CSV file with no blanks, only one row of data is submitted even though all rows are valid. >.<

Comment: I have edited the op. "// we can go through our file again and insert values" does this mean another while loop like "while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",")) !==false){"

Comment: This almost works thank you u_mulder I'll have to mess with it to get it right.